# E: Unable to locate package airodump-ng

Tags: wireless, command-line, aircrack-ng

So I have installed aircrack-ng and now trying to install `airodump-ng` but I am getting the following error message.

```
E: Unable to locate package airodump-ng
```

Question is, do I still need airdump if I have already installed aircrack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I remember, `airodump-ng` is a part of [aircrack-ng [image: Install aircrack-ng]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aircrack-ng) so it should be installed already.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the `aircrack-ng` package, you already have the `airodump-ng` executable:

```
ek@Apok:~$ airodump-ng
The program 'airodump-ng' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

Just run it. ([Here's how.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/airodump-ng.1.html))

As for whether or not you *need* to use `airodump-ng`, that depends. From the [official site](http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng):

> Airodump-ng is used for packet capturing of raw 802.11 frames and is particularly suitable for collecting WEP [IVs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (Initialization Vector) for the intent of using them with [aircrack-ng](/doku.php?id=aircrack-ng&DokuWiki=0ae5ea9c478aaa5fe595f87d09b5555.). If you have a GPS receiver connected to the computer, airodump-ng is capable of logging the coordinates of the found access points.

If you need to do any of that, you should likely run `airodump-ng`. Otherwise, you may not need it.

Comment: To be dead honest I am attempting to hack a wireless network. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Clint Well I certainly assume you *are* trying to "hack" a wireless network (listen in, or break in), as that's the primary purpose of `aircrack-ng` and all the utilities contained therein. There are many legitimate and even lawful situations where you can do this. But cracking an encrypted wireless network, for example if it's not yours or if it is but violates a duty of privacy, is sometimes illegal and/or can subject you to civil liability, and may also be unethical. Tools like `aircrack-ng` and `airodump-ng` should use used responsibly. (Disclosure: I am not a lawyer.)